# Minecraft not loading

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, nintendo-switch

Just now, I decided to play Minecraft, so, I got my Nintendo Switch, turned it on, and went into the game. Before that, I was playing Mario Kart 8 Deluxe, so I had to close that and then go into the game. When I went into the game, it showed me the regular screen (By "Regular Screen" I mean the screen that appears when you first load up the game with the Play button, settings button, and marketplace buttons.) and then suddenly showed me another screen that told me that Minecraft had an update. This was weird because normally for Nintendo Switch, it tells you that yeou have a software update *before* you open the game. I then proceeded to download the update, and everything seemed to be fine. Then, I tried opening the game again, and nothing. It showed me the little Nintendo Switch animation on the bottom right and top left of the screen, but after that, it just showed me a blank screen.

My question is: What is wrong? How can I fix it? And Will I lose any of my Minecraft Worlds or worse, lose the game?

Some Notes:

I am on the Nintendo Switch update 12.0.3 (Which I have seen that it causes update issues, maybe this is the problem?)

I *have* update the Switch before updating Minecraft to 1.17 (No problem)

I am now on the version after 1.17.1 of Minecraft (I can tell what version it is when I go into the options menu for Minecraft. I'm not on the actually game though, I am still on the Nintendo Switch Home Screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution! Simply turning on and off the Nintendo Switch will make it load much much more faster. I have only been putting it in sleep mode for quite a while, and have never truly turned off my Nintendo Switch (Besides sleep mode). What I did was hold down the power button, select "Turn off", turn back on my Nintendo Switch, loaded in Minecraft, and it only gave me a black screen for about 2 seconds before turning to the red "Mojang" screen, and then allowing me to select my worlds.